Trying to remember the name of an avant garde movie from the '70s
So, I remember watching this film for an avant-garde film class a few years back, but I can't remember its name. I'm pretty sure it was made in the '70s (though it could have been from the late '60s or early '80s).
What I remember is that it centered around various actors reading/performing the same single scene over and over again in different settings. There may have also been a segment or two where the crew expresses their frustration with the director on camera (though I may be conflating two films that I watched at around the same time). It was in English - definitely an American indie film. I wanted to look up some of the actors who participated in the project/film, but it's a bit difficult to do that without the film title!
Edit:
I remembered a couple things that might be useful...
The scene was about a couple (man and woman), and was often (if not usually) shot outside. I seem to recall a pair of African American actors doing the scene near/in front of a brick wall. And I think there may have been a couple of renditions of the scene in a park and/or on a bridge (though I think with different actors).

A long shot, but maybe the Beaver Trilogy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beaver_Trilogy)? It has basically the same scene filmed with different actors in 1979, 1981, and 1985, though the complete film wasn't released until 2001.

Thanks, but unfortunately that's not it. I do believe there were some big names involved, but not Sean Penn or Crispin Glover, as far as I know.

I found it! I finally found it! (I was actually looking for another Criterion Collection film from roughly the same era, but I stumbled onto the Criterion Collection page for this one.) Looking at it, I am thoroughly unsurprised that it was so hard to find. It's called Symbiopsychotaxiplasm Take One, and it was made in 1968. Apparently a sequel was made much, much later (like, early 2000s), and Steve Buscemi was actually involved in that - the sequel, I mean - but as an executive producer more than an actor. The Criterion Collection gives this description of Symbiopsychotaxiplasm Take One:

In his one-of-a-kind fiction/documentary hybrid Symbiopsychotaxiplasm
  Take One, director William Greaves presides over a beleaguered film
  crew in New York’s Central Park, leaving them to try to figure out
  what kind of movie they’re making. A couple enacts a break-up scenario
  over and over, a documentary crew films a crew filming the crew,
  locals wander casually into the frame: the project defies easy
  description. Yet this wildly innovative sixties counterculture
  landmark remains one of the most tightly focused and insightful movies
  ever made about making movies. Criterion presents this long-unreleased
  gem in a special two-disc edition, along with its sequel, Take 2½,
  made thirty-five years later with executive producers Steven
  Soderbergh and Steve Buscemi.


Could it be 'Living in Oblivion' from 1995?  It's a low budget film about the making of a low budget film. There's a scene where the actors cannot get the line right and have to redo it over and over.
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113677/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_83

No - the movie is definitely older than that (as per the question, think late '60s to early '80s). There may be one or two well-known actors, but they only have bit roles. (And I'm 90% sure that Steve Buscemi wasn't one of them.) Plus, the film I'm thinking of was very much about filming/thinking about this one scene (which wasn't really part of anything else) in different contexts, and not so much about making an entire film. But thanks for trying!
